# Missing order number

Tags: magento

I`m using Magento 1.6.1.0 From time to time we have a missing order number. 
For example:

100003354
100003353
100003351
100003350

So the 100003352 is missing. Nobody deletes the order number. We can not figure out how this can be happen. The only thing we detect is that the next number is the same order. This we know, because we wrote an extension that always sent us an E-Mail when an order is placed and before it is in the system. And so we get an E-Mail with the order number 100003352 but in the system it is missing. Minutes later comes the 100003353 with the same data. This behaviour is seldom and it also happened before we wrote the extension. Maybe someone has an idea? Thanks!
Sebastian

Comment: Is the email being sent before the order is being recorded in the database?

Comment: yes, th mail will be sent before the order is recorded.

Comment: Commonly, when a database INSERT fails, the ID number is still incremented (depending on db config). Can you see the database logs? And/or create exception logging for your app?

Answer (score 3):

Failed credit card authorizations do this. The order gets assigned a SO number to go along with the request to the gateway for card authorization. If the authorization fails, it stays reserved for that order until a valid credit card is entered. The next order placed gets assigned a new number on the next order submission. This causes skips when people do not complete the order on failed authorizations and out of order invoice numbers when they complete these orders later.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting abandoned carts.  Check under Admin -> Reports -> Shopping Cart -> Abandoned Carts.

Comment: Very strange, every time we've seen that the order numbers showed up as an abandoned cart.  Have you checked your payment gateway's logs?  Do you see anything in there around the time that the order numbers go missing?